# How to store X and Y coordinates, after clicking on a button to store it

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

im trying to store the x and y coordinates after clicking on the canvas, i can set a marker position, i can show the x an y coordinates and a picture of a marker on that position, but now i want to store these coordinates so that when you reload the web browser, the marker position wil still be at his place where you first placed it.

full code down..

```
var context = (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext("2d")

//Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "http://antyradar.info/wp-content/uploads/commercial-tumilty-design-commercial-floor-plans.jpg";

var Marker = function () {
this.Sprite = new Image();
this.Sprite.src = "https://www.lasvegas-waterdelivery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/5gal-cropped.png"
this.Width = 12;
this.Height = 20;
this.XPos = 0;
this.YPos = 0;
}

  var Markers = new Array();
  var rect = (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getBoundingClientRect();

  var mouseClicked = function (mouse) {
  // Get current mouse coords
  var mouseXPos = (mouse.x - rect.left);
  var mouseYPos = (mouse.y - rect.top);



  console.log("x: " + mouseXPos);
  console.log("y: " + mouseYPos)
  console.log("Marker added");

  // Move the marker when placed to a better location
  var marker = new Marker();
  marker.XPos = mouseXPos - (marker.Width * 37.7);
  marker.YPos = mouseYPos - (marker.Height * 7);

  Markers.push(marker);

  for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
    if(i > 1){
      Markers.splice(marker);
    }
  }


  sessionStorage.setItem('Marker', JSON.stringify(marker));
  let store = sessionStorage.getItem('Marker');

  console.log(store);

  var remember = function(){
    return store;
  }
}

// Add mouse click event listener to canvas
/* (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClicked, false); */

var firstLoad = function () {
  context.font = "15px Georgia";
  context.textAlign = "center";
}

firstLoad();

var main = function () {
  draw();
};

var width = (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).width
var height = (this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).height
var draw = function () {
  // Clear Canvas
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // Draw map
  // Sprite, X location, Y location, Image width, Image height
  // You can leave the image height and width off, if you do it will draw the image at default size
  context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 700, 700);

  // Draw markers
  for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
    var tempMarker = Markers[i];
    // Draw marker
    context.drawImage(tempMarker.Sprite, tempMarker.XPos, tempMarker.YPos, tempMarker.Width, tempMarker.Height);
  }
};

setInterval(main, (1000 / 10)); // Refresh 60 times a second
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store your coordinates.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Marker', JSON.stringify(marker));
```

Comment: the sessionStorage works i can get the coordinates, but if i refresh, the place of the marker disappears, do you know how it keeps the marker on his place after it refreshes?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. In your case, I need more details about the Marker class and how you manage the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If this is ionic 3 store the information in a Provider too keep it consistent from page to page/on refresh or use a service for ionic 4 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUvDM55PN9k - tutorial). To keep the information after closing and opening the app you could use the ionic file plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file or other such native storage.